# C#, Need to obtain file creation time

Tags: c#, .net

I am having some issues with the following code:

```
string today = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(mySettings._TempDataStoragePath);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo f in files) 
{
    string fileDate = f.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();                   
    if (fileDate.Equals(today)) 
    {
                    ...
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that `f.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();` is returning today's date and not the actual creation date of the file.

I need to be able to inspect the real creation time.

I suspect DirectoryInfo is returning temp copies and not a reference to the real thing.

How do I obtain the real creation time?

Comment: Goto windows explorer, check the file properties and verify whether `FileInfo.CreationTime` is same as time in properties window. It should be. If it is then file is created today only without any doubt.

Comment: What filesystem format is the directory in? NTFS? FAT?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: Why are you converting a datetime to a string and then comparing?  It works, I guess - just sloppy.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339658/file-creation-time-in-c-sharp

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be running into an issue called the [file tunneling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime(v=vs.110).aspx) in the OS. The `CreationFile` property is indeed the creation file of the actual file and not a temp. However, the date returned may not be accurate as this information is cached in the OS due to the fact that applications usually delete and add the same file instead of changing it.

Call `Refresh` on the `FileInfo` before getting the creation time. That may help.