# Getting the Creation Date of a .txt C#

Tags: c#, file, date

I need to get the date of a .txt file located somewhere in the C:\ directory.

I used ->

```
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\\docname.txt");
```

and wrote it to the console like this `Console.WriteLine(fileCreatedDate.ToString())`

what I got was `12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM` which isn't possible because I created the document today. Can someone explain?

I am still learning how to get the creation date of a file and this was my first attempt but I am very curious to why this happened. Thanks!

Comment: 1600 sounds correct

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339658/file-creation-time-in-c-sharp
You may need to refresh the file info. Or verify that the file is actually being read, it looks like the default return value is being returned.

Comment: It's either `@"C:\docname.txt"` or `"C:\\docname.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the default time because the file does not exist.

[As specified in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1):

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this
> method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated
> Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

This can result in `12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM`

Maybe add a check if the file exists before trying to retrieve the creation date.